# How to use tomcat authentication with cookies enabled?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, cookies, tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I use JDBCRealm to authenticate users and I want the users need not to login again when they come back a couple of days later.

But there seems no configuration here for me to enable cookie authentication in tomcat!?

I am using tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported, you'll have to implement a custom AuthenticationRealm to get this feature, or switch to a framework that provides authentication methods.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could you please list some authentication framework that supports this?